# My javascript validation for my email, dosen't work

Tags: javascript, validation

we've made a validation in javascript. 
firs and second name validation works, but not the email 
in another project, it does work, but you can't "send it" 
we would be really happy if anyone knows how to solve this problem,

the code looks like this:

```
function validateRegUserInsert() {
    firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
    lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
    email = document.getElementById("email");
    pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");


    if(validateName(firstname.value)){

    } 
    else {
        alert("Se till att ditt förnamn inte innehåller siffror eller att fältet är tomt!");
        return false;
    }

    if(validateName(lastname.value)){

    } 
    else{
        alert("Se till att ditt efternamn inte innehåller siffror eller att fältet är tomt!");
        return false;
    }

    if(validateEmail(email.value)){

    } 
    else{
        alert("Se till att skriva en giltig emailadress!");
        return false;
    }

    if(pwd.value.length > 5){

    } 
    else{
        alert("Ditt lösenord måste innehålla minst 6 tecken!");
        return false;
    }
    regUser();
    return false;   
}



function validateName(name) { 
    var re = /^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/;
    return re.test(name);
}


function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\]+)*)|(\.+\))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
    }
```

Comment: you always return false?

Comment: where shouldn't i return false?

Comment: Validating an email address is no trivial task. The best solution is to use HTML5's `<input type="email">` or just match against `\S+@\S+.\S+` and send an email to confirm. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: yeah i know that it's but we have a javascript project så we have to do the validation in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

your regex doesn't work maybe:

try this one:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tBhm2/)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)